# Responsive design to shrink a div when it's sibling's width increases

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to fix a bug with a website where the header contains two elements, a div floated left and a `ul` floated right.

Normally, the two sit next to each other, but occasionally the content of the `ul` is large and as the two connect the div stays on the line but the `ul` drops to the next line. I want to prevent this by sacrificing width on the `div` and having the text on two lines.

The best I've been able to do so far is to set the width on the left `div` explicitly in px, but that makes everything two lines when it should only be when it needs to. Every other thing I've tried around display and min/max width hasn't had much affect.

I'll not post the full markup here but it goes a little something like this

```
<div id="minibasketAndLogin">
    <div id="login"><!--omitted--></div>
    <ul class="basketLoginList">
        <li><!--there are 7 li's in this list--></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

The css is also rather convoluted so I won't include it here, but the whole thing can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dashood/f2tt50uj/).

Basically, as the `ul` stretches, the `div` should shrink and it's text wrap to the next line.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this - set the container as `table` and two elements inside as `table-cell`, so they will always stay next to each other. For keeping the list items on a single line, set `white-space:nowrap;` on the `ul`, and `display:inline-block;` on the `li`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc9u272t/2/)

```css
#minibasketAndLogin {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#login, .basketLoginList {
    display: table-cell;
}
.basketLoginList {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.basketLoginList li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="minibasketAndLogin">
    <div id="login">Login as John Doe</div>
    <ul class="basketLoginList">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good answer and very close to what I'm looking for. I had tried table display as it seemed to be the behaviour I was after. The existing markup is a bit messy so it might just need stripping back as there's a lot going on. Is it possible to make it so the ul on the right doesn't ever go to a 2nd line? With all the site CSS applied the ul is formatted for one line only so the div on the left needs to yield as much space as possible.

Comment: I don't quite get it, there is only on `ul` and it always stays on the right, do you mean the `li` items? do you mean `white-space:nowrap;`? that will trigger the scrollbar if there is not enough room for the content. Or maybe you could post an image to explain it.

Comment: Yes, sorry what I meant was to keep the `li` elements on a single line, preferably without specifying width since I never know how much width is required as users interact with the pages the content will change. I need for the `ul` and `li` to stretch as necessary and for the `div` to yield space to it to keep the `li` on a single line.

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dashood/2kdydtqk/1/ as you reduce the width of the result window then the `div` text should drop to a 2nd line but all `li` stay on a single line formatting.

Comment: How about this? - http://jsfiddle.net/2kdydtqk/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/2kdydtqk/3/

Comment: The second one is perfect! Thank so much, really appreciate the help!